# Google Maps API: Get url for current view

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a form where users can introduce google maps urls to specify the address of some stuff.
I've been thinking in showing a map through Google Map API v3, letting user move to desired location and through a button or something automatically get the url of the place and copy it to an input.

I've been able to display the map using the tutorial, but I haven't been able to find in the documentation how I could get the url...

I think you will not need it, but this is the simple code I'm using:

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
var options = {
zoom: 8,
center: latlng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
mapTypeControl: false
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-box'), options );
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd suggest using `map.getCenter().toUrlValue()` and `map.getZoom()` to obtain the centre and zoom state of the current map view. That information should let you build a URI that you can then use, bare in mind that you'll need to write some code to take the values off the URI and pass them to the map API.

Comment: Nice, that gave me the coordinates, with that I think I'll be able to construct the url. thanks.